# When Dealing with Databases on Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I've been using docker locally for a while and one of the issues I've had is when, inexplicably, the docker container dies and it takes all the data with it. Obviously, this can not happen in production.

What are some of the things I can do to safeguard my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally to protect the data and to version your application you would separate any data from the container, you can do this with docker volumes, cloud block storage or object storage in your application, depending on the use case - storage persists even after you destroy the container and you can attach and detach the volumes between containers etc.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

> Mount a host directory as a data volume In addition to creating a
>   volume using the -v flag you can also mount a directory from your
>   Engine daemon’s host into a container.
>
> $ docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp
>   training/webapp python app.py This command mounts the host directory,
>   /src/webapp, into the container at /opt/webapp. If the path
>   /opt/webapp already exists inside the container’s image, the
>   /src/webapp mount overlays but does not remove the pre-existing
>   content. Once the mount is removed, the content is accessible again.
>   This is consistent with the expected behavior of the mount command.
>
> The container-dir must always be an absolute path such as /src/docs.
>   The host-dir can either be an absolute path or a name value. If you
>   supply an absolute path for the host-dir, Docker bind-mounts to the
>   path you specify. If you supply a name, Docker creates a named volume
>   by that name.
>
> A name value must start with an alphanumeric character, followed by
>   a-z0-9, _ (underscore), . (period) or - (hyphen). An absolute path
>   starts with a / (forward slash).
>
> For example, you can specify either /foo or foo for a host-dir value.
>   If you supply the /foo value, Engine creates a bind-mount. If you
>   supply the foo specification, Engine creates a named volume.
>
> If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Engine daemon
>   has only limited access to your OS X or Windows filesystem. Docker
>   Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (OS X) or C:\Users (Windows)
>   directory. So, you can mount files or directories on OS X using.

Comment: Would you know if this practice still be applicable to Amazon EC2 Container services?

Comment: yep, it applies to anything than runs docker and can be presented with host or network storage - on AWS I would suggest EBS backed instances or attaching EBS volumes to use as Docker volumes would be even better - the container, like the cloud instance, should be disposable and just running a service, what's import is your docker file.https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/